# add_post_meta on subcription renewal

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm able to add/edit custom fields after a user completes an order with the `add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'function_name_here', 10, 1);` hook. Does this also apply when a subscription auto renews or is there another action hook that should be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using subscriptions plugin, then all the actions are listed here : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/

i think it `woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete` that you are looking for.